# Why Python SDK is not returning Datasets from Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I created File Dataset in Azure Machine Learning, but I can't retrieve it using Python SDK - I get empty dictionary. I am using the code below:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

ws = Workspace.from_config()
print(Dataset.get_all(workspace=ws))
```

The dataset is visible in both Azure Machine Learning Studio UI as well as in Azure Machine Learning extension for VS Code, shown below:
[image]

Why is that? I am not using VNet or VPN.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to [consume the v1 File.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-data)

```
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = ''
resource_group = ''
workspace_name = ''

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='mydataset')
dataset.download(target_path='.', overwrite=False)
```

[Data Types in AML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L1m7.png)